# simple login session php

Tags: php, session, authentication, phpmyadmin

Having trouble getting my session up and running. I've been over looking my code for the past couple hours and I can't see to find what is wrong with it. The problem I am experiencing is that every time I type the username and password in, it just redirects me to the login page to type in the info again when it should be displaying the securedpage.php..

Here is my code:

**loginproc.php page** - This page steps through if statement and goes straight to the else

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('../../model/database.php');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$login = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (username = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']) . "') and (password = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']) . "')");

// Check username and password match
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
// Jump to secured page
header('Location: securedpage.php');
}
else {
// Jump to login page
header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

**securedpage.php page**

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Check, if username session is NOT set then this page will jump to login page
if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
<html>

<head>
<title>Secured Page</title>
</head>

<body>

<p>This is secured page with session: <b><?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?></b>
<br>You can put your restricted information here.</p>
<p><a href="logout.php">Logout</a></p>

</body>

</html>
```

**database.php page**

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sports_db';
$username = '';
$password = '';
$options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

try {
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    include 'errors/db_error_connect.php';
    exit;
}

function display_db_error($error_message) {
    global $app_path;
    include 'errors/db_error.php';
    exit;
}
?>
```

Comment: confirm that whether is record fetching from `DB` or not for given username and password

Comment: can you do a var_dump for `$login`?

Comment: So what value does `mysql_num_rows($login)` return? Print it to debug

Comment: Test whether `$_POST["username"]` and `$_POST["password"]` are properly set. It maybe a problem with your login-page.

Comment: mysql_num_rows($login) just returns 0

Comment: Then that's where the problem lies, now check what does `mysql_query` return? If it returns false then your query is not executing fine and has an error. If it returns true then that means there is no user with that username and password

Comment: try to echo  `mysql_error()` after your `mysql_query`.And please learing `PDO` ir `mysqli_*`

Comment: when I echo the mysql_error() it says "no database selected"

Comment: But I'm using this database for all my selection statements throughout the site and they're working fine.

Comment: @user2446521 change `include('../../model/database.php');` to `require_once('../../model/database.php')`.

Comment: Still getting same error :(

Comment: What are the contents of `database.php`

Comment: Just added the database.php page above in an edit. I took out the pass and user just for posting purposes

Comment: @user2446521 This will not work .. you are creating PDO connection and using `mysql_*` here . I am amazed how code on your other files are working with `mysql`. Either change connection to `mysql` or the query for login to `PDO` . This should help you ... And please use `@username` before sending message to any SO user. It will notify him in his Inbox

Comment: @Let'sCode Okay thanks for helping.. What would I use instead of mysql_num_rows?

Comment: @Let'sCode nvm I got it working now.. if you want to post that as a answer so I can check it off. Thanks for helping

Comment: @user2446521 check my answer .. and reply me if its what you want or you want something changed ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot mix PDO and mysql .. You are creating query in `PDO` and using `mysql_*` 
Try changing your code to

```
<?php

// Inialize session
session_start();

// Include database connection settings
include('../../model/database.php');

// Retrieve username and password from database according to user's input
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM user WHERE (`username` = :username) and (`password` = :password)");

$result = $stmt->execute(array(':username'=>$_POST['username'],':password'=>$_POST['password']));
$num_rows = $stmt->rowCount();
// Check username and password match
if ( $num_rows > 0) {
// Set username session variable
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
// Jump to secured page
header('Location: securedpage.php');
}
else {
// Jump to login page
header('Location: index.php');
}

?>
```

see [**`reference`**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: perfect! thank you, I understand completely that I can't mix PDO and mysql_*

Answer (score 0):

The problem probably lies here:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($login) == 1) {
```

Use triple equation if you want to check for the integer 1. Most likely, though, is that the login/pass fails.

And this:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
```

is bad practice, even if you get a valid response.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking me to do

Comment: Well, as you write above, you get mysql_num_rows($login) == 0, which means login/pass fails.

Comment: In short, verify that the username and password you're checking really does exist in the databases (could simply be that you're sending spaces in the username or password).

Second, by handling the _POST data directly you're blindly trusting the submitted login and password. Using mysql_real_escape_string is not enough to secure yourself again SQL injection techniques.

Comment: Yes I am entering the correct values and the database has the correct values.

Comment: You need to find out the number of rows returned from your query. If the number of rows returned from that query is set to 1, then you'll be redirected accordingly and the session variable will be set.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if your query doesn't return any rows, either the username or the password is wrong. Try dumping the query string and run that manually through the SQL console (or something like phpmyadmin). Also, as suggested above, try var_dump($login). Finally, have a look at the html form used to send the data (could be that you're using method="get")

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion for you:

1) Do not store the user given data directly in to your session variable.

2) First check to see if the user credential exists in your table,fetch the corresponding row and then store the fetched data in your session variable.