# Session data not being passed through to the next page

Tags: php, pdo

I have a login system that has two pages, it's quite simple but it doesn't appear that the data is being passed through as I am being redirected back. I have tried a couple solutions. Adding exit; and die; after the inital redirect from the login. I have also printed the session_id which worked fine.

Login page:

```
session_start();

if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $username = strip_tags($_POST['username']);
    $password = strip_tags($_POST['password']);

    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);

    $password = md5($password);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE username = :username LIMIT 1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    foreach($stmt as $row) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $db_password = $row['password'];
    }

    if($password == $db_password){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header("Location: admin.php");
        exit;
    }else{
        echo "You did not enter the correct details.";
    }
}
```

This is the admin page. It just redirects back to login and doesn't get any further down the page

```
session_start();

if(!isset($_SESSION['id'])){
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Comment: have you looked at **$password == $db_password** returns **true**?

Comment: It does redirect as on the admin.php page I can echo and die; remaining there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [simple login session php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889995/simple-login-session-php)

Comment: Didi you try to echo something on the admin page?

Comment: yes and that did work

Comment: Did you try to hard code the  value like  `$_SESSION['id'] = 123`

Comment: Working now, was a small syntax error, id should have been Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)**

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure.

You need to fetch data form result set as

```
 $stmt->execute();
 $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);// fetch data
 $id = $row['id'];
 $db_password = $row['password'];
 if($password == $db_password){// then compair
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
    header("Location: admin.php");
    exit;
}else{
    echo "You did not enter the correct details.";
}
```

Comment: I get two errors with this code, undefined id and password

Comment: Ahh my mistake change $result to $row

Comment: yeah I get through but still getting redirected back to the login page

Comment: echo `$password` and `$db_password` and post its value

Comment: My error, id should have been Id. Thanks for the answer though!